# NodeJS only listen to a connection that uses a specific VPN service

Tags: node.js, vpn

I want to create a website that can only be accessed when using a specific VPN service. I'm using nodeJS to create the server. I don't have any specific VPN service to be used right now but i'm open to suggestions. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS EC2, VPC and Direct Connect to solve this problem.

Run your nodejs server on EC2 and use Direct Connect to connect to your server.

If you want to maintain all this by yourself, you can use open-vpn between your server and to your local network.

Comment: Can you elaborate the "use open-vpn between your server and to your local network." part? Does this mean, I would use open-vpn on my server and client?

Comment: Yes. You can use other compatible openvpn clients as well. I have used openvpn and compatible with all operating systems. Clients available for all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think to achieve this is by getting tge VPN's ip address range and then creating firewall rules that whitelist those ip ranges